# Incorrect SQL Syntax SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, geolocation

I am fairly new to using SQL, and I know my syntax is incorrect, and I am having some issues getting this right. I would like to create a function that calculates distance between two locations that contain latitude and longitude. My tables are named Comm and Fac and both have latitude and longitude columns.The are located within a database called Fac_Comm (tables are both on the same server). I want to group by ASU CODE and then return the distance in miles.

The errors I have received: the variables are not declared, multi-part identifier of Fac_Comm.Comm.Latitude could not be bound and incorrect syntax near GROUP.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Miles
(
       @latitude_1 float,
       @longitude_1 float,
       @latitude_2 float,
       @longitude_2 float
)
RETURNS int    
AS
BEGIN
        DECLARE @radiusOfTheEarth int 
        SET @radiusOfTheEarth = 6371--km

        DECLARE @distance int  

        SELECT Fac_Comm.Comm.Latitude,
        Fac_Comm.Comm.Longitude,
        Fac_Comm.Fac.Latitude,
        Fac_Comm.Fac.Longitude

       SELECT @distance = ( @radiusOfTheEarth 
        * acos( cos( radians(@latitude_1) ) 
        * cos( radians( @latitude_2 ) ) 
        * cos( radians( @longitude_2 ) - radians(@longitude_1) ) + sin( 
     radians(@latitude_1) )  * sin( radians( @latitude_2 ) ) ) )
GROUP BY Fac_Comm.Fac.ASUCODE, Fac_Comm.Comm.ASUCODE
       RETURN @distance
END
```

Comment: though input float and output INT it wouldn't be a good practice without converting within the function as the numbers will vary. So, it would be better to return float or use a proper convert and round to get an accurate distance.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you are looking for. You were very close.

For your function, you don't have any columns really, you're doing a calculation based on all of your input parameters. So you didn't need the first `SELECT` clause. `GROUP BY` is used for combining like rows of data, with functions like `SUM` or `AVG` to aggregate data.

You're just returning a single value and doing some math.

```
CREATE FUNCTION Miles
(
       @latitude_1 float,
       @longitude_1 float,
       @latitude_2 float,
       @longitude_2 float
)
RETURNS int    
AS
BEGIN
        DECLARE @radiusOfTheEarth int 
        DECLARE @distance int
        SET @radiusOfTheEarth = 6371--km

        SELECT @distance = ( @radiusOfTheEarth 
        * acos( cos( radians(@latitude_1) ) 
        * cos( radians( @latitude_2 ) ) 
        * cos( radians( @longitude_2 ) - radians(@longitude_1) ) 
        + sin( radians(@latitude_1) )  * sin( radians( @latitude_2 ) ) ) )

   RETURN @distance
END
```

I also moved one of your variable declarations, to keep them all together. There was nothing wrong with the syntax, though. Just a good practice.

One thing to note, using `SELECT` to set a variable value is specific to T-SQL language used in SQL SERVER. `SET` is the ANSI Standard.

I also realized that you might wonder how to call the function. We can use some of the code we removed from the function.

Rather than reference the database in every part of the query, which is a bit messy, we can tell SSMS to `USE` The Fac_Comm database, and set the database context for all of the following statements. I have added this to the beginning of the query

Call the function you named `Miles` in the `SELECT`statement. In this case, the four columns are being passed as parameters, and the resulting column "DistanceInMiles". Also included the ASUCODE column, so that the output shows which code is associated with the Miles calculation.

I made one assumption, that you meant a `JOIN` and not a `GROUP BY`. That will combine the tables where there is a record in both matching ASUCODE. So if this query does not run, feel free to comment and I can update the post to fix it.

```
USE Fac_Comm; 

    SELECT [dbo].[Miles](Comm.Latitude, 
                         Comm.Longitude,
                         Fac.Latitude,
                         Fac.Longitude) AS DistanceInMiles,
                 Comm.[ASUCODE]

    FROM Comm
    JOIN Fac 
    ON Comm.[ASUCODE] = Fac.[ASUCODE]
```

Hope this helps! feel free to comment if you have questions or problems.

Comment: I am getting an error that says "Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 30
Ambiguous column name 'ASUCODE'."

Comment: Oops sorry! That's because both Fac and Comm have the same column. You can use `Comm.[ASUCODE]` instead. I updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

There are several immediately visible problems:
1. You have a SELECT and a GROUP BY, but between those two you need a FROM. **Fac_Comm.Comm.Latitude** means that you have a schema name 'Fac_Comm', a table in that schema named 'Comm', and there's a column in that table named 'Latitude'. If the tables are in the dbo schema, the correct reference would be  **Fac_Comm.dbo.Comm.Latitude**.

```
FROM Fac_Comm.dbo.Comm
```

after the SELECT but before the GROUP BY

2. You SELECT @distance, but you have never SET it to anything.  Are you trying to SET it with your SELECT?
3. You repeat the SELECT keyword in what I think is a single query